# Is there a way to see negative values on the unity timeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a unity project. When recording a negative keyframe in the timeline, the line dips out of the screen.
It seems to only show the positive values, is there any way I can view the negative ones?

[image]

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

it took a while but i have the answer. docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/EditingCurves.html all I had to do was to press F.